Saving/Opening PDF in Compose Multiplatform
I have question regarding if my approach would be correct for Compose Multiplatform and Compose in general, because I have doubts that my current approach could cause unnecessary recompositions. Generally it works as expected and after logging for a bit, I didn't see any unecessary recompositions. Unfortunately I couldn't come up with better solution.
Here is my composable screen. As you can see I call if statements in composable body, which is discouraged, but in my case I have to wait for result from saving PDF action, therefore these FileManager implementations are composable functions.
        val fileManager = koinInject<FileManager>()
        var openFileTrigger by remember { mutableStateOf(FileReference("")) }

        LaunchedEffect(lifecycleOwner.lifecycle) {
            lifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                reportModel.uiEvent.collectLatest { event ->
                    when (event) {
                        is UiEvent.Navigate -> {
                            with(localNavigator) {
                                replace(event.screen)
                            }
                        }

                        else -> {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        if (state.value.fileByteArray != null) {
            fileManager.SavePdfToFile(
                fileName = "report${Clock.System.now().toLocalDateTime(TimeZone.currentSystemDefault()).date}.pdf",
                pdfContent = state.value.fileByteArray,
                onResultAction = {
                    openFileTrigger = it
                    reportModel.onEvent(ReportEvent.OnClearByteArray)
                }
            )
        }

        if (openFileTrigger.path.isNotEmpty()) {
            fileManager.OpenPdfFile(openFileTrigger)
            openFileTrigger = FileReference("")
        }

expect class FileManager {

    @Composable
    fun SavePdfToFile(fileName: String, pdfContent: ByteArray?, onResultAction: (FileReference) -> Unit)

    @Composable
    fun OpenPdfFile(fileReference: FileReference)
}

data class FileReference(val path: String)


actual class FileManager() {

    @Composable
    actual fun SavePdfToFile(fileName: String, pdfContent: ByteArray?, onResultAction: (FileReference) -> Unit) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            onResult = { uri ->
                try {
                    uri.data?.data?.let {
                        context.contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(it, "w")?.use { pfd ->
                            FileOutputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor).use { outputStream ->
                                outputStream.write(pdfContent)
                            }
                        }
                        onResultAction(FileReference(uri.data?.dataString ?: ""))
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Napier.e("Error saving PDF", e, "SavePdfToFile")
                }
            }
        )


        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT).apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
            type = "application/pdf"
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, fileName)

        }

        LaunchedEffect(pdfContent) {
            if (pdfContent != null) {
                launcher.launch(intent)
            }
        }

    }


    @OptIn(ExperimentalResourceApi::class)
    @Composable
    actual fun OpenPdfFile(fileReference: FileReference) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val uri = Uri.parse(fileReference.path)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply {
            setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
            flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
        }

        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, stringResource(Res.string.open_pdf)))
    }
}

